# Export TS Types with CommonJS Require

Tags: node.js, typescript, commonjs

Given file A.ts:

```
interface B {};
export = {};
```

and file C.ts:

```
import A = require("./A");
var c: B; // Typescript error: Cannot find name
```

How do I make interfaces declared in A.ts visible in C.ts **while still using the CommonJS import style (i.e. `require`)**?

I've tried `var c: A.B` but that does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be fine with the folowing structure:

A.ts

```
export interface A 
{
    SomeProperty: number;
}
```

C.ts

```
import { A } from './A';

var x: A = {SomeProperty: 123}; //OK
var x1: A = {OtherProperty: 123}; //Not OK
```

UPDATE

You can also go with writing definition file like this:

A.d.ts

```
interface B 
{
    SomeProperty: number;
}
```

C.ts

```
/// <reference path="A.d.ts" />

var c: B;
c.SomeProperty; //OK
```

Comment: Thank you, but as stated in the question, I can't move away from the CommonJS import system (i.e. `require`). I need a way to make it work without changing my import style.

Comment: I am using `import { A } from './A'` syntax without any problems in project targeting commonjs - why cant you use it?

Comment: Because the files I'm importing are largely using `module.exports` and it's too much of a hassle to change them so they are acceptable typescript modules.

Comment: So you mean you are unable to change the structure of A.ts?

Comment: I'm unable to change the export structure of A.ts, but since I'm just now adding the type information, I could change how I declare the interfaces.

Comment: I am afraid it might not be possible to export interfaces using node.js `exports` because interfaces are compile type only and therefore cannot be emited as part of `exports` object.

Comment: But is there no other way to define my interfaces and have them available everywhere?

Comment: Check my update. I think you can go with definitions.

Comment: Wohoo, it works! However, some comments: it seems I don't need the `declare` keyword, or the reference thing, because it works without them. Maybe you could expand on that?

Comment: you are correct - declare with interface makes no sense. Regarding reference - it might be needed in cases when compiler/IDE cannot find interface see more: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html

Answer (score 1):

> The export = syntax specifies a single object that is exported from
>   the module. This can be a class, interface, namespace, function, or
>   enum.

from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

So now you export empty class.

Try file A.ts:

```
interface B {};
export = B;
```

and file C.ts:

```
import B = require("./A");
var c: B;
```